# Webview is disposed when swiping the Carousel Page

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a CarouselPage that have three page and Webview is in the first page. There is no problem between webViewPage and second page but Whenever swiping third page, webview is recreating and refreshing.

This behavior is works good on iOS.

Expected Behavior
When we return to the webview page, it should present the webview as we left it.

XF 5.0.0.2244

in the App.css;

```
CarouselPage carouselPage = new CarouselPage();
carouselPage.Children.Add(new Page1()); // webViewPage
carouselPage.Children.Add(new Page2()); 
carouselPage.Children.Add(new Page3());
```

Page1.xaml;

```
<WebView Source="www.stackoverflow.com" MinimumHeightRequest="300"/>
```

[image]

Comment: where is the relevant code?

Comment: Hi @Jason, thanks for your reply. I've added a few line codes. There is no need more code to test it.

Comment: On Android, the WebView is reloaded When switching to another tab , the page's OnDisappearing will be called. If you return to the previous page, the OnAppearing method is trigerred, which is the reason to make the webView be reloaded.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, what should be the solution about it?

Comment: I can't see any solution, try post it on github

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT thanks. I've posted it 5 days ago but unfortunately no any response.. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14953